# Google Play store issue security breach

Tags: security

My daughter got an Samsung Galaxy 3 7" tablet for Xmas. She also got some Google Play gift cards. My husband put in a credit card to buy a game for her. The next day there were 4 games downloaded that she did not pick - and not to her tablet. We had to cancel the credit card. Now her Google Play app will not connect to the internet even though she can access it via typing in from internet. Games she did buy are not showing up on her tablet. Google Play, Amazon and Samsungs reg site who up on her tablet as having bad certificates???? I have searched the google play site and can't find a place to access her gift cards to see if they have a balance or have been used.